# Currentproject.connection works without linked tables?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a linked table connected to the SQL Server backend. I went to the linked tables option in Access and deleted the connection which means there are no linked tables any more. However, when I go to debug console and type `?currentproject.Connection`, I get the same connection string I got when I had the linked tables. The connection strings looks like this

```
 Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\COMP\COMPMAIN.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System3.mdw;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Access Connectivity Engine;Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=True;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False
```

However, even though the connection string is exactly the same when I remove the linked tables a simple code like this

```
Function connection()
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
rst.Open "select * from Customers", CurrentProject.connection
Do While Not rst.EOF
i = i + 1
rst.MoveNext
Loop
Debug.Print i

End Function
```

Which used to return 124 when I had linked tables

Gives me the follow error

> Microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query

I am confused because the error does not say the connection is invalid but says cannot find the table

Comment: Try Compact and Repair to force MS Access to clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentproject.Connection` in `.mdb` points to this `.mdb` itself. Not to linked tables!
When you had have linked tables in your `.mdb` your code established connection to this `.mdb` and pulled data from linked table reference placed there. When you  deleted linked table from `.mdb` your code establishes connection to `.mdb` but can not find table(as you have deleted it).

Connection string for linked table is stored in `.Connect` property:

```
CurrentDB.TableDefs("Customers").Connect
```